# Change of coordinates in Jacobi's principle derivation

Tags: calculus-of-variations

For a system whose lagrangian function does not contain time explicitly, let n+1 variables $q_1,...,q_n,t$ be given as functions of some parameter $\tau$. The action integral becomes
$$A=\int_{\tau_1}^{\tau_2} L\left(q_1,...,q_n;\frac{q'_1}{t'},...,\frac{q'_n}{t'}\right)~t'~d\tau$$

In configuration space the kinetic energy of the system can be written as the kinetic energy of a single particle of mass 1:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2$$
but since our independent variable is no longer t but $\tau$ we get 
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{ds}{d\tau}\right)^2~/~t'^2$$

This seems like a simple change of variables but I'm getting caught up on it. I was thinking that I need to do
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{ds}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt'}\frac{dt'}{dt}$$

but I'm not seeing how to do $\frac{d\tau}{dt'}$ or $\frac{dt'}{dt}$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!